# Python syntax: if A and B in C do something

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to write the following piece of code as part of a bigger script (I don't think the rest of the script is relevant for this particular question, but let me know if it is!):

```
if A and B in C:
   print("Ok!")
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the string "Ok" is printed not when both conditions are met (`if A and B in C`) but also when just one of them happens, that is, "Ok" is printed even when only A is in C but B is not.

Any ideas about what I might be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: That's `if A and (B in C):`...

Comment: `A and B in C` doesn't do what you think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write it like this:

```
if A in C and B in C:
   # do your thing
```

What's happening with your code is that even though it sounds amazing in plain English (*"if A and B in C"*) it's actually being evaluated like this:

```
if (A) and (B in C):
    # your thing
```

So, when the `A` object `is not None` then the first part of the `and` clause will evaluate to `True` and the result will depend on whether `B` is `in C` or not.

So, you need to use the `in` operator separately in both sides of `and` clause as I suggested:

```
if (A in C) and (B in C):
    # your thing (parenthesis not needed, but explicitly put there for clarity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all()`.

```
if all(x in C for x in [A,B]):
    #do your thing
```